# Asp.Net Core API shuts down automatically when authorize is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have created an Asp.Net Web API for google authentication and here is my code in `satrtup.cs`

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "591241482908-66qgk38nbf1un6xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                options.ClientSecret = "GOCSPX-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            });
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

And there is Login Controller

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return Ok(this.User);
        }
    }
```

Now the code builds successfully, but whenever I run the web API the console and the application shuts down automatically. How Can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post your debug output?

Comment: Has the problem solved? If not, can you provide the debug or exception information? So that we can help you solve the problem.